# Symfony2.3 - dynamically Generate Forms Based on user Data

Tags: forms, symfony

I try to struggling through generating a form based on User Data with the help of the [Symfony-Book][1]

The Form appears, but the data doesn't base on the querybuilder and I have no idea, where I'm going wrong. The formular shows all objects of the entity, but not the limited defined in querybuilder

My formtype:

```
<?php

namespace Pso\ProjectBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;


class ProjectuserType extends AbstractType
{

    private $id;

    public function __construct($id)
    {$this->id = $id;}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

$id = $this->id;

$builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($id) {
            $form = $event->getForm();

            $formOptions = array(
                'class' => 'Pso\LogBundle\Entity\User',
                'property' => 'username',
                'multiple' => 'true',
                'expanded' => 'true',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use($id)  {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('x')->FROM('PsoProjectBundle:project', 'p')
                                                       ->JOIN('p.users','u')
                                                       ->WHERE('p.id <>:id')
                                                       ->setParameter('id', $id)
                                                        ;
                },
            );

            $form->add('user', 'entity', $formOptions)
                 ->add('Submit', 'submit', array(
            'attr'=> array (
                'formnovalidate' => 'formnovalidate'
            )
        ));
        }
    );
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'Projectuser';
}


}
```

UPDATE:

Now I try to change my query in the builder so that it looks:

```
<?php

namespace Pso\ProjectBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;


class ProjectuserType extends AbstractType
{

private $id;

public function __construct($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

$id = $this->id;

$builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($id) {
            $form = $event->getForm();

            $formOptions = array(
                'class' => 'Pso\LogBundle\Entity\User',
                'property' => 'username',
                'multiple' => 'true',
                'expanded' => 'true',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use($id)  {


                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('x')->SELECT('u')
                                                       ->FROM('PsoLogBundle:user', 'u')
                                                       ->JOIN('PsoProjectBundle:project', 'p')
                                                       ->WHERE('p.id <>:id')
                                                       ->setParameter('id', $id)
                                                        ;
                },
            );


            $form->add('user', 'entity', $formOptions)
                 ->add('Submit', 'submit', array(
            'attr'=> array (
                'formnovalidate' => 'formnovalidate'
            )
        ));
        }
    );
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'Projectuser';
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class'  => 'Pso\LogBundle\Entity\User',
    ));
}
```

}

In this case I get the error

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 79: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query
>   \Lexer::T_WITH, got ','

UPDATE:

Controller:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
         ->add('projectuser', ['except_id' => $id])
         ->getForm();
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $build['form'] = $form->createView();   
    return $this->render('PsoProjectBundle:Project:editProject.html.twig', array('projects' =>$projects, 'users' =>$users, 'form' => $form->createView(), ));
```

ProjectuserType.php:

```
<?php
class ProjectuserType extends AbstractType
{

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
\assert(isset($options['except_id']));
$exceptId = $options['except_id'];

$formOptions = [
  'class' => User::class, // PHP5.5
  'property' => 'username',
  'multiple' => 'true',
  'expanded' => 'true',
  'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use($exceptId)  {
    return $er
      ->createQueryBuilder('u')
      ->join('u.project', 'p')
      ->where('p.id <> :id')
      ->setParameter('id', $exceptId)
    ;
  }
];

$submitOptions = [
  'attr'=> [
    'formnovalidate' => 'formnovalidate'
  ]
];


$builder
  ->add('user', 'entity', $formOptions)
  ->add('Submit', 'submit', $submitOptions)
;
}

public function getName()
{
return 'Projectuser';
  }

  public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
  $resolver->setDefaults([
    'data_class'  => FormUser::class, // that line is wrong in your code! it must be a class with attributes 'user' and 'submit', see the "builder->add" calls
]);

$resolver->setRequired(['except_id']);
 }
}
```

Comment: So you are trying to fill out the forms with data from the user? First, I would confirm that the query returns the results you are looking for (in a test case outside of the form builder).

Comment: Yes I try to fill it with data from the entity user. The Query returns results, when I call it from the controller in the repository. Can the error be a result, because I have no "->SELECT('u') in the querybuilder? When I try this I get a new error "[Syntax Error] line 0, col 79: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_WITH, got ',' "

Comment: If you join you can write `->join('u.project', 'p')` by joining via ORM attribute or `->join('PsoProjectBundle:project', 'p', Join::WITH, 'u.project = p.id')`

Answer (score 0):

FormTypes should have default-ctors or service-parameters, because you can register them as a service to be able to create your form like:

```
<?php
// in the controller action (didn't test it)
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($dataObject)
  ->add('projectuser', [
    'except_id' => $yourId
  ])
  ->getForm();
```

That is not because it's easier to write, but you don't want to take care of how to create the Type. If your Type depends on another service you don't want to change your application and simply edit the services.yml.

So pass your id via the options parameter and configure your ProjectuserType to allow that option. Drop that event listener. I've build the craziest forms, but never ever needed those events.

// edit try this:

```
<?php
class ProjectuserType extends AbstractType
{

  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    \assert(isset($options['except_id']));
    $exceptId = $options['except_id'];

    $formOptions = [
      'class' => User::class, // PHP5.5
      'property' => 'username',
      'multiple' => 'true',
      'expanded' => 'true',
      'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use($exceptId)  {
        return $er
          ->createQueryBuilder('u')
          ->join('u.project', 'p')
          ->where('p.id <> :id')
          ->setParameter('id', $exceptId)
        ;
      }
    ];

    $submitOptions = [
      'attr'=> [
        'formnovalidate' => 'formnovalidate'
      ]
    ];


    $builder
      ->add('user', 'entity', $formOptions)
      ->add('Submit', 'submit', $submitOptions)
    ;
}

  public function getName()
  {
    return 'Projectuser';
  }

  public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
  {
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class'  => FormUser::class, // that line is wrong in your code! it must be a class with attributes 'user' and 'submit', see the "builder->add" calls
    ]);

    $resolver->setRequired(['except_id']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch it. I'm newbie at symfony and doctrine. ;-) $dataObject is the variable for the options. In that case for $yourId? I prefer to build my Selects without querybuilder in the repository-file. Would it be good practice to pass the result of such a select in repository to the formbuilder? Could I do this also with the $dataObject?

Comment: @Micha no it isn't good to pass the result to a selectbox although it would be easier for you to understand :). From the point of view, when you create the form you say: "add the type ProjectuserType with id e.g. 5". You don't want to pollute your controller action with other stuff like read from the db. The dataObject is the result of the form, not the options.

Comment: Thanks, I see it never could be good practice. My Problem is, that I have a more complicate Select in the formbuilder with joining tables etc. With your code from the controller I can pass the Id to the builder, when I got that right. But what is on the site of the builder? How do I get there a select go working, which seems to be my problem in the moment. I prefer to create queries without the query builder. Do you have a link to a good documentation or something linke that. Symfony-Documentation put me in the direction of event listener :-)

Comment: I've edited my answer with some code (not tested). Do you get it now :) ?

Comment: One of my big mistakes seems to was, that I created an unidirectional many-to-many-relationship between project and user. I corrected this and now I get only an error about the variable $dataObject, which isn't known. When I try it with event Listener, it is a problem with the class FormUser, which is not a valid class. When I add the line >  $resolver->setRequired('$id'); i get the error
>ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver::setRequired() must be of the type array, string given,

Comment: The form component of symfony uses DataAccessors. If you pass an object, than it will use `get/set/is/has` methods to access an attribute. If you pass an array then it will access it directly. I'm a fan of objects where possible so you create a new class FormUser with user and submit attributes or you don't use `data_class` and $form->getData() gives you an array. Look at http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.html#method_createFormBuilder the data parameter is mixed.

Comment: When I don't want to create a class FormUser, I can skip the part >public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
Is this right? 
Then it works, but I have to look again, because now all users from the entity where displayed, so it seems that the form doesn't display the result of select but all elements of entity

Comment: no you have to allow and require the `except_id` option.

Comment: ah ok, thanks. Now I only have a problem, cause with your code except_id would be a array, but id is a value. When I get the error right >Expected argument of type "string or Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface", "array" given